# If $ (a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence, then $ \arctan(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence.

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

We know that if a function $f:A\mapsto\mathbb{R}$, $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}$, is uniformly continuous on $A$ then, if ($a_n$) is a Cauchy sequence in $A$, then ($f(a_n))$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

We know $\arctan$ is uniformly continuous on $A=\mathbb{R}$ however since the range of the function is $(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2})\subsetneq\mathbb{R}$ and the definition is a function from $A\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, does this still apply? Intuitively, for this case, it seems so but I just want to make sure I'm not forgetting a possibility where it doesn't work.

Thank you.

Comment: If $f$ maps $A$ to $B\subset \mathbb{R}$, then it also maps $A$ to $\mathbb{R}$ (it's just not onto, but that's not part of the definition). So yes, the criterion applies.

Comment: arctan is uniformly continuous, why do you doubt? Of cause it is true.

Comment: $\arctan$ *is* a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$...

Comment: Why do lecturers feel the need to make contrived examples of uniform continuity? I've seen *actual uses* of uniform continuity (i.e. where it was a helpful tool)... This problem can be solved with continuity only: by noting that in $R$, all Cauchy sequences converge, and so $\arctan a_n$ converges to $\  \lim_{n\to\infty} \arctan \left( a_n \right)  = \arctan \left( \lim_{n\to\infty} a_n\right) =  $.

Comment: @Thomas I don't know why I made it more complicated than it was. Thank you for clarifying that it doesn't have to be onto/surjective.

Comment: This is indirectly relevant: defining $\rho(x, y)=|\arctan(x)-\arctan(y)|$ yields aleatoric on $\mathbb{R}$ that is equivalent to the usual metric on the real line $\mathbb{R}$ ($d(x,y)=|x-y|$). The completion of the$\mathbb{R}$ relative to the metric $\rho$ is the extended real line  $[-\infty,\infty]$. For example, notice that the sequence $a_n=n$ is a Cauchy sequence w.r.t. $\rho$. This moreorless coincides with the notion that $\lim_na_n=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

For functions $f : X \to Y$ the meaning of the word "range" is not standardized. Some people understand it is as the codomain $Y$ of $f$, other people understand it is a as the image $f(X) \subset Y$ of $f$. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Range_of_a_function).

Let us come to the  $\arctan$-function (principal value). We can understand it is a bijective function $\arctan  : \mathbb R \to (-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ with codomain $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ or as an injective function $\arctan  : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ with image $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. In my opinion there is no "correct" interpretation, it is a matter of taste.

You say that

- We know that if a function $f:A \to \mathbb R$, $A \subset \mathbb R$, is uniformly continuous on $A$, then if $(a_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence in $A$, then $(f(a_n))$ is also a Cauchy sequence.

Your doubt seems to be this:

You know that $\arctan$ is uniformly continuous on $A= \mathbb R$, but you regard it as a function with codomain $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ and not as a function with codomain $\mathbb R$. So why does the above bullet point apply here?

The uniform continuity of a real-valued function $f$ does not depend on the understanding of the codomain of $f$. In our case the metric on $(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$ is the restriction of the metric on $\mathbb R$. In both sets it is given by $\lvert a - b \rvert$. In other words, we may regard $\arctan$ as a function with codomain $\mathbb  R$ so that the above bullet point applies.

Answer (score -1):

Since $(a_{n})$ is Cauchy it converges to some value $\ell$. Arctan is a continuous function on the reals and at $\ell$ as consequence. Therefore by Cauchy criterion of continuouty $f(a_n)$ converges as well.

Comment: This should have been written in a comment (like I did), because obviously the lecturer wants this to be solved using uniform continuity.

Comment: TheSilverdoe, 1/x isn't continous on the reals

Comment: No reason for downvoting.